# SwiftUI Button opacity within a list doesn't apply to its background

Tags: swift, list, button, swiftui, opacity

I have a button at the bottom of a screen inside a list. I can successfully hide the button text through opacity, however the background remains white as shown in the image. I'm trying to remove the text and the background to make it completely invisible. Note that I do want to retain that background feature for the list items therefore .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) is not an option on the list.

```
List {
   Section {
    // ...
}
   Section {
    // ...
}
   Button(action: {
      for member in fetchedMembers {
          managedObjectContext.delete(member)
      }
      loadEIPFActive.toggle()
      deleteAllActive.toggle()
   }, label: {
       Text("Delete All")
   })
   .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
   .foregroundColor(.red)
   .opacity(deleteAllActive ? 1 : 0)

}
```

[image: Snap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like LuLuGaGa's suggestion to use an `if` statement to remove the button entirely. But if you don't like that, you can use the `listRowBackground` modifier.

Also, it might be better to set the button's role to `.destructive` instead of specifying an explicit `PlainButtonStyle()` and `foregroundColor(.red)`. Red may not the appropriate color in all cultures, and `.destructive` makes the button red if appropriate (and if you don't override the button style).

```
            Button(role: .destructive) {
                // blah blah blah
            } label: {
                Text("Delete All")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .opacity(deleteAllActive ? 1 : 0)
            .listRowBackground(deleteAllActive ? nil : Color.clear)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you could just use an if:

```
if deleteAllActive {
   Button(
       role: .destructive,
       action:  {
           //...
       },
       label:  {
           Text("Delete All")
       }
   )
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```